# PHP MYSQL SELECT BETWEEN DATE'S

Tags: php, mysql, date, select

Hello i trying to select date from mysql between date's with this code:

```
if (empty($_GET['date-range1'])) { 
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sohy_raports ORDER BY ".$_GET['sort']." ".$_GET['ad']."");

} else {
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sohy_raports WHERE date BETWEEN ".$_GET['date-range1']." AND ".$_GET['date-range2']." ORDER BY ".$_GET['sort']." ".$_GET['ad']."");
}
```

but with this code i can't select between date's only between id's. It can be from date format error Y-mm-dd ?

Thanks

Comment: Just a comment: you should write timestamps to the database, makes this question alot easier

Comment: What are the contents of `$_GET['date-range1']` and `$_GET['date-range2']` ? Also, your code is widely open to SQL injection attacks, you might want to read up on that if you plan on putting this code on the public internet.

Comment: What is the data type of the date column? What are the inputs? Why aren't you quoting those date values? Why aren't you using query parameters?

Comment: your code will never go for else condition if `$_GET['date-range1']` is empty then how it will check for between and you missed comma between sort and ad..

Comment: date-range1 = 2013-05-23;    date-range2 = 2013-05-28;

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sohy_raports WHERE date BETWEEN ".$_GET['date-range1']." AND ".$_GET['date-range2']." ORDER BY ".$_GET['sort']." ".$_GET['ad']."");
```

do

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM sohy_raports WHERE date BETWEEN ".$_GET['date-range1']." AND ".$_GET['date-range2']." ORDER BY ".$_GET['sort']." ".$_GET['ad'];
echo $query;
$sql=mysql_query($query);
```

This will print out the query you are sending to your database, and will clear up alot of what might go wrong, and what exactly the date-format is you are using.

On the side, but no less important:
 - Don't use the mysql_* functions anymore, they are deprecated and unsafe. Switch to mysqli_* or PDO instead.
 - Never just use your GET variable (or POST) in your query, make sure you sanitize them first to prevent SQL injections.